# Compactness criterion on subsets of fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Are there sufficient conditions for a family of functions $F \subset H^s_0(\Omega)$ $(s>0)$ to be relatively compact in $H^s_0(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact. $n$ is some positive integer.

Comment: To be uniformly bounded in $H^t$ with $t>s$ should work I think.